# CountIf where the starting cell is dependent on what is inputted in another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I will base my explanation off the example photo I have given. Essentially I have a CountIf equation where it always takes place in the D Column and the furthest cell down is always D10, however, the top most cell for the scan is dependent on what is inputted in F3. For example if someone enters **4** into F3 then the result in E3 should update to 4 (Because a =Countif(D**4**:D10,1) is 4). If someone enters **5** into D3 then the result should be 3 (Because a =Countif(D**5**:D10,1) is 4).

If someone enters 6 into F3 then start the scan at D6 etc.

A lot of the formula I don't want to change, only the D Cell number in the first half of the formula.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX:

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(D1:D10,F3):D10,1)
```

[image]